# Print List of Reports Found For Each Email

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an assignment where I have over 1000 reports going out to tons of different emails together. I had to separate the emails receiving those reports into 9 different columns in this excel sheet because per report a random amount of people between 1-9 could receive it and I want to see which reports each email receives. I made a new sheet in which it has all emails listed from the 1-9 columns in one column and deleted duplicates. I am left with 79 emails. The 1000+ reports I have I want to show under each email individually. For example lets say one email address receives 25 of the reports I want it to find those reports and put them into another column next to the email receiving them so I can get a list for each email. Due to confidentiality reasons I can't upload the document but if you need more information I should be able to provide some.

I have messed with Hlookup and Vlookup but was unsuccessful.

I was trying code like =HLOOKUP(A2,'Find it EZ Report Schedule'!J:R,'Find it EZ Report Schedule'!A:A,FALSE)

It should have in column 1: email@email.com and column 2 should be Report 1 Report Two Report Three... etc.

Example Pictures to possibly help explain what I am wanting
[This is a basic example of how the reports and emails receiving them looks except in a much larger amount than I showed in example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tb9.png)

[In this sheet page I am trying to put each email and have it list each report it's receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPlqk.png)

If this helps explain what I am trying to do let me know!

Comment: Your question is not clear. I suggest to show an example how your input data looks like. (You could create a table as text in a code block.)

Comment: Trying to use an Index function now just not sure how to get it to work with my specific example.

Comment: =INDEX('Find it EZ Report Schedule'!A:A,MATCH('Individual Emails For Reports'!$A$2,'Find it EZ Report Schedule'!J2:R2,0)) I tried this but it was only giving me the response of whatever matched in the 'Find it EZ Report Schedule'!A:A field and wasn't actually verifying email was matching.

Comment: You should add to the question what you tried and what is the result. Should output `Reports` column contain concatenation of report names separated with spaces? Better should show a complete hand-made example output for your example input. Use code blocks (indented by 4 spaces) or back-ticks for formulas. It would be better to show input and output table contents as formatted text in a code block like this: `_ | A  | B                     | C                               | D ` ...   `...`  `---------------------`
`2 | R1 | tolna@2019z.ga        | tolna@g0zr2ynshlth0lu4.cf       |...`